# Change VSCode remote temporary directory during extension installation process

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Update: extension installation doesn't go through `/tmp` now so this issue is obsolete.

---

I connected to a remote host via `Remote-SSH` extension successfully.

When I tried to install extensions on the remote host, the process failed because I don't have write access to `/tmp`, and VSCode seems to use the `/tmp` directory to download(?) or store some temporary files. Is there a setting I can use to change it to my home directory where I have write permission so I can install Python extension on the remote host?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have root access to the remote server?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Maybe you could open an issue on GitHub to ask <https://github.com/microsoft/vscode>

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to let VSCode use a different folder as temporary data folder.

On Linux, you may do so by setting the environment variable `TMPDIR` to the path to a folder on which you have write access. Then run VSCode, as following:

```
TMPDIR="path-to-a-folder-with-write-access" code
```

See more about setting a custom temporary directory [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/change-tmp-directory-path#temporary-directory-variables-and-location)